# Footer not showing on TableView unless I scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uiview

I added a Footer to my `TableView` that is displayed at the bottom of the view. However, the footer is not visible unless I scroll down, then it shows up.

Here's what I'm talking about:
[image: Invisible Footer]

I have not populated the `TableView` yet, but I do not think that's an issue. Here's the code that I've written for the footer:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(footerView)

    //x, y, w, h constraints
    footerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    //Send Button
    let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    footerView.addSubview(sendButton)

    //x, y, w, h Button constraints
    sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    //Text Field
    footerView.addSubview(inputTextField)

    //x, y, w, h Text Field constraints
    inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    inputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    // Separator
    let separatorLineView = UIView()
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(220/255), green: CGFloat(220/255), blue: CGFloat(220/255), alpha: 0.1)
    separatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    footerView.addSubview(separatorLineView)

    //x, y, w, h separator constraints
    separatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    return footerView
}
```

The way I want the footer to work is to show up as soon as the user navigates to the view, then move up as the keyboard shows up, and move down when keyboard is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding the `footerView` as subview to another `UIView`.

You should remove the following code:

```
footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(footerView)

    //x, y, w, h constraints
    footerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    footerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

The `UITableView` will handle the placement of the footer view.

If, as I suspect, you intend to have the `footerView` pinned to the bottom of the view, then you shouldn't be returning this as a footer view of the table view. It should be separate from the `UITableView` hierarchy.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your last sentence? 
If I shouldn't return the footer view, what should I return? That is, if I should return anything at all.